# Usage of IcmpSendEcho2 with an asynchronous callback

Tags: winapi, asynchronous, apc, ping, icmp

I've been reading the [MSDN documentation for IcmpSendEcho2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366051.aspx) and it raises more questions than it answers.

I'm familiar with asynchronous callbacks from other Win32 APIs such as `ReadFileEx`... I provide a buffer which I guarantee will be reserved for the driver's use until the operation completes with any result other than `IO_PENDING`, I get my callback in case of either success or failure (and call `GetCompletionStatus` to find out which).  Timeouts are my responsibility and I can call `CancelIo` to abort processing, but the buffer is still reserved until the driver cancels the operation and calls my completion routine with a status of `CANCELLED`.  And there's an `OVERLAPPED` structure which uniquely identifies the request through all of this.

`IcmpSendEcho2` doesn't use an `OVERLAPPED` context structure for asynchronous requests.  And the documentation is <strike>unclear</strike> *excessively minimalist* about what happens if the ping times out or fails (failure would be lack of a network connection, a missing ARP entry for local peers, ICMP destination unreachable response from an intervening router for remote peers, etc).

Does anyone know whether the callback occurs on timeout and/or failure?  And especially, if no response comes, can I reuse the buffer for another call to `IcmpSendEcho2` or is it forever reserved in case a reply comes in late?

I'm wanting to use this function from a Win32 service, which means I have to get the error-handling cases right and I can't just leak buffers (or if the API does leak buffers, I have to use a helper process so I have a way to abandon requests).

There's also an ugly incompatibility in the way the callback is made.  It looks like the first parameter is consistent between the two signatures, so I should be able to use the newer `PIO_APC_ROUTINE` as long as I only use the second parameter if an OS version check returns Vista or newer?  Although MSDN says "don't do a Windows version check", it seems like I need to, because the set of versions with the new argument aren't the same as the set of versions where the function exists in iphlpapi.dll.

Pointers to additional documentation or working code which uses this function and an APC would be much appreciated.

Please also let me know if this is completely the wrong approach -- i.e. if either using raw sockets or some combination of `IcmpCreateFile`+`WriteFileEx`+`ReadFileEx` would be more robust.

Answer (score 1):

I use `IcmpSendEcho2` with an event, not a callback, but I think the flow is the same in both cases. `IcmpSendEcho2` uses `NtDeviceIoControlFile` internally. It detects some ICMP-related errors early on and returns them as error codes in the 12xx range. If (and only if) `IcmpSendEcho2` returns `ERROR_IO_PENDING`, it will eventually call the callback and/or set the event, *regardless* of whether the ping succeeds, fails or times out. Any buffers you pass in must be preserved until then, but can be reused afterwards.

As for the version check, you can avoid it at a slight cost by using an event with `RegisterWaitForSingleObject` instead of an APC callback.

Comment: My experience with IcmpSendEcho2Ex, called with an event, and a callback function, and a timeout, is that the documented Vista style callback may get called, but the only valid argument is the first one, for the XP style callback.  If the event has not yet fired, then I also preserve the memory until the timeout expires. There does not appear to be any _safe_ way to cancel the request.  More details here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.networks/Kyi5lKgGdxM